# Array and while scanf crash

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, scanf

```
#define LEN 200
int main()
{
    int arr[LEN],i;
    for (i =0; i < LEN; i++)
        while(scanf("%d", arr[LEN]) == 1){
            if((arr[LEN] == arr[LEN]+1) || arr[LEN] < 0){
            printf("Bad numbers.\n");
            }
            else if(arr[LEN] == 0){
                break;
            }
        }
    printf("Break");
return 0;
}
```

My point is if I'm writing numbers that are different and greater than 0 and `arr[5]` is different from `a[12]` or `a[any other]` it should save it into the array.  But else if `arr[LEN] == 0` it should stop `scanf` and save read numbers into the array and then continue with other stuff. After a few numbers, my code crashed. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

1. Inside the for loop, you need to use arr[i] instead of `arr[LEN]`. Truly speaking, `arr[LEN]` declaration creates an array of name arr with index ranging from `0` to `LEN-1`. So `arr[LEN]` is out of range of your array.
2. In `scanf`, you need to use `&arr[i]` instead of `arr[LEN]`.
3. In the `if` condition you need to write `if(arr[i] == arr[i-1])` because you can compare presently input value only with previous value, not with next value which has not been entered yet. But make sure you handle this condition separately for `i=0` because then `i-1` will not be an element of array.

I think these changes will make your code work smoothly for all values.
Also, if you want to make sure that all array values are different then you have to compare present input value with all the previously stored values. Because current value might be different from just previous value but may be similar to value entered even before that.

Comment: Please take a moment to try out what the icons above the textbox where you type your answer do (you can always cancel the changes). They can transform your wall-of-text into something more readable and understandable with little extra effort.

Comment: The return value from `scanf("%d", &arr[i])` is 1 if the conversion succeeds; it would be 0 if there is data in the input but it doesn't match a decimal integer (e.g. a letter), or EOF (always negative, usually -1) if there is no data left to read or there is some error on the device being read. The [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) function never returns the length of the input. If there are multiple conversion specifications, it will return the number of successful conversions — but suppressed assignments (`%*d` etc) and `%n` are not counted.

Comment: I can't up-vote an otherwise good answer until you fix item 4.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me

Comment: I will surely keep these things in mind from next time onwards.